# How are Spark native functions routed to implementations?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking at [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#from_json)

I see this function created as an expression [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/FunctionRegistry.scala#L560), where it's creating an instance of `JsonToStructs` via class loading the constructor [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/FunctionRegistry.scala#L598-L647), and then finally loaded into the registry [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/FunctionRegistry.scala#L587-L593).

From my understanding, this will allow `from_json` to be called in Spark sql like so:

```
SELECT from_json( '{"data":[{"id":123, "quantity":2, "price":39.5}]}', 
'data array<struct<id:INT, quantity:INT, price:DOUBLE>>') 
AS product_details;
```

However, the argument types shown in the spark docs (and what I used above) for `from_json` are different than any of the [implementations](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L4138-L4282). I don't know how they work with the `JsonToStructs` class, which has this constructor:

```
case class JsonToStructs(
  schema: DataType,
  options: Map[String, String],
  child: Expression,
  timeZoneId: Option[String] = None)
```

I'm obviously missing something basic here -- what is the link between `from_json` and `JsonToStructs`?

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the answer:

The implementations I linked above for `from_json` are specific to using these functions in actual code like Java/Scala for spark.sql functionality and have nothing to do with being registered in the Spark catalog.

It looks like `JsonToStructs` is the only piece of code I have to look at. There are [overloading constructors](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/jsonExpressions.scala#L535-L543) that take in expressions and can be processed as literals, which is why the `from_json` calls in the Spark docs are using Strings. `JsonToStructs` also defines how to parse the JSON data and convert according to the provided schema.

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.